# Node.js middlware function concept

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am working on Nodejs/Express Js, Right now i am working on "middleware function", following is example of middleware function,Here is my current code

```
const authMiddleware = (req, res, next) => {
  if (req.headers.authorization === 'secret-token') {
    next(); // Proceed to the next middleware or route handler
  } else {
    res.status(401).send('Unauthorized');
  }
};

// Using the middleware function for a specific route
app.get('/api/protected', authMiddleware, (req, res) => {
  res.send('Protected route');
});
```

I want to know that if condition match(secret-token match/inside "if condition") then function redirect to "api/protected" function ?

Comment: It will redirect to whatever you pass as an argument in the `next` as the callback function, this hands off control. As the `app.get` essentially acts as a listener on the `'api/protected'` route, unless I am misunderstanding your question

Comment: And how we can pass argument inside "next" middleware ?

Comment: It's just whatever is in the stack (see `app.use`). You can also override it by passing a route as an argument.